# Unresolved external __imp_strdup in Windows Runtime Component

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm writing a Windows Runtime Component to expose some C libraries to my C# app. When I build, I'm getting a bunch of unresolved external errors for C stdlib functions like __imp_strdup. Is there a way to fix this? Searching on the internet suggests statically linking the C runtime library (compile with /MD) but this isn't supported in UWP.

EDIT: To clarify, the project is a Windows Runtime Component C++ library in Visual Studio 2017. I've included the source for the libraries locally because this is one of the requirements to expose them to my C# app, as detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=vs-2017#BK_WinRTComponent

Comment: How are you building your C code? What toolset? What kind of project?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to write a Windows Runtime Component project in C++. Added these details to the original question as well for clarification.